# Postgres DB Dump Carries Owner Information With It

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am setting up a system of DB backup for a web project. At the moment, the DB is being backed up via Bash script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set the DB configuration
export PGHOST=localhost
export PGPORT=5432
#export PGDATABASE=yoga
#export PGUSER=delme
export PGDATABASE=projectA
export PGUSER=userA
export PGPASSWORD=blah-blah

# Backs up mydatabase to a file and then uploads it to AWS S3.
# First, dump database backup to a file
TIME=$(date "+%s")
BACKUP_FILE="postgres_${PGDATABASE}_${TIME}.pgdump"
echo "Backing up $PGDATABASE to $BACKUP_FILE"
pg_dump --format=custom > $BACKUP_FILE
```

In the cluster, I have the following roles

```
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 delme     | Superuser                                                  | {}
 userA     |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

The list of databases

```
postgres=# \list
                              List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 projectA  | userA    | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/userA          +
           |          |          |         |         | userA=CTc/userA
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 yoga      | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
(5 rows)
```

Whenever I bring this dump on a local machine and try to restore via `pg_restore --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=postgres --verbose --create --dbname=new_db_name --format=custom --clean postgres_projectA_1660909386.pgdump`, I get about 200 errors.

Most errors are of the following format:

```
pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE OWNED BY "public.plugins_mentorsplugin_mentors_id_seq"
pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.plugins_plugingeneral"
pg_restore: from TOC entry 374; 1259 19889 TABLE plugins_plugingeneral delme
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  role "delme" does not exist
Command was: ALTER TABLE public.plugins_plugingeneral OWNER TO delme;

pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.plugins_retreatcommentplugin"
pg_restore: from TOC entry 375; 1259 19892 TABLE plugins_retreatcommentplugin delme
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  role "delme" does not exist
Command was: ALTER TABLE public.plugins_retreatcommentplugin OWNER TO delme;

pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.plugins_retreatcommentplugin_comments"
pg_restore: from TOC entry 376; 1259 19895 TABLE plugins_retreatcommentplugin_comments delme
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  role "delme" does not exist
Command was: ALTER TABLE public.plugins_retreatcommentplugin_comments OWNER TO delme;

pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE "public.plugins_retreatcommentplugin_comments_id_seq"
pg_restore: from TOC entry 377; 1259 19898 SEQUENCE plugins_retreatcommentplugin_comments_id_seq delme
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  role "delme" does not exist
Command was: ALTER TABLE public.plugins_retreatcommentplugin_comments_id_seq OWNER TO delme;

pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE OWNED BY "public.plugins_retreatcommentplugin_comments_id_seq"
pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.plugins_retreatdayplan"
pg_restore: from TOC entry 378; 1259 19900 TABLE plugins_retreatdayplan delme
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  role "delme" does not exist
Command was: ALTER TABLE public.plugins_retreatdayplan OWNER TO delme;
```

In short, the restoration does not work, so my thinking is to troubleshoot these errors. What is causing the Postgres to bring this information into the dump, despite my creating a new database with a new connection user? How can I make these errors go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--no-owner` flag prevents writing ownership when used with `pg_dump`.

Alternatively use `--no-owner` with `pg_restore` to avoid restoring ownership. All objects created will then belong to the user that was used to run `pg_restore` (in your example all of them would belong to `postgres`)

Comment: Thanks. Is that a good idea to assign them to `postgres`? Should I assign them to the user I use to connect to the DB?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to have them owned by Postgres. Create a regular user and the target database (e.g. owned by the regular user) before restoring using the superuser, then run pg_restore as the regular user (without the --create option)